# Why does my phone browser look different than developer tools of pcs

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, screen

When I want to see how my website looks like on cell phones, well I go to the developer tools of my browser (chrome) and change page sizes to check different sizes. I've manually added the screen size of my own phone. But it looks different when I actually view my website through my phone. Why is that?!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, you'll see this button in the developer options:
[image]

Click it, and Chrome will do it's best job at emulating a mobile device.

You can chose which model of phone you want to emulate with.
[image]

Comment: To answer why, it's probably due to some weird browser specific stuff happening.

Comment: does it look different if you use chrome with your phone?

Comment: @JoshDaBosh Probably. But I was actually looking for a solution :D
and yes I use developer tool with that button on.

Comment: @ShrewdStyle Yes it looks different no idea why.